# ASP.NET event wiring does not work correctly if the page has many controls in IE8 native mode

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, callback, servercontrols

Well, it looks like IE8 in native mode doesn't like ASP.NET event wiring. I have few heavy pages developed in ASP.NET 2.0. By heavy I mean having lots of server controls and callback controls. The final actions are Apply and Cancel but user sets data of controls through Callback calls.

I have seen that when Apply button is clicked it called standard ASP.NET page event like Page_load, init, etc multiple times. And as a result, functionality is not working as expected. These pages are working perfectly OK when the application is launched in IE7 or IE8(IE7 emulated mode).

Its not possible to attach code because its huge and proprietary. I am wondering if any one of you come across similar issue for ASP.NET app launched from IE8.

Appreciate any pointers.

Thanks,
Dhananjay

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on several ASP.NET 2.0 Web Forms apps in IE8 Native Mode and haven't had any issues.

Those page events are all wired up on the server side, so unless you have some strange javascript running post-backs on the page...the browser shouldn't influence how many times those are getting called.

I'd check any of your custom javascript and make sure there isn't submitting your form back to the server multiple times per submit.

Comment: Thank you Justin for replying to the question.

Well, I know that the event wiring is done at server side. However it is the client which initiate request to server - and that is where I suspect the problem is.

If I add custom header for page to render in IE7 emulation mode, the page just works normally.

Unfortunately I can't share the code base with you OR even can't create sample application to repo the issue due to time constraint. As I pointed, I have fixed the issue by adding custom header in the ASPX page. This is for time being rather than permanent and looking for the root cause.